# How to find if command executed in exec command fails?

Tags: php

I need to know that If I call a php script execution command through exec command and the script execution fails due to any reason say "file not found" , then how can I find it out.
I have following command :

```
    $cmd="php testfile.php" ;
    $outputfile="testoutput.txt";
    exec(sprintf("%s > %s 2>&1 & echo $!", $cmd, $outputfile),$pidArr, $status);
```

exec command return -1 in case of error but in this case exec is executing successfully ie $status is coming 0 in my case but the "php testfile.php" command is failing, the output is getting in testoutput.txt. 
But I need to know the way so that I can identify it after exec if the command is failed.
I could think of the option of reading testoutput.txt and grep for fail or error word, but I dont think it is reliable.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can receive the output result of the exec function by passing an optional second parameter:

So you could execute the exec() with that 3rd arg, then check if it is non-zero for an error condition.

```
exec("blah blah blah", $output, $result); 
if($result > 0) 
{ 
   die('error message here'); 
}
```

If you don't find the error through that second parameter, you can search for the error log of apache, for example in Ubuntu Server 12.10 through the command $ tail /var/log/apache2/error.log

let me know if i can help you more.

Comment: I tried it, actually it third argument is giving 0 in my case, file it was an file not found error

Comment: so might be you should have to find apace error or any other exception handling method to trace it.

Comment: Yes, I am trying out the same thing but thought to find if its the only method for the same.

Comment: I am getting error "Could not open input file" in testoutput.txt I mentioned in the code, not even in apache error.

Comment: http://christian-dorr.com/using-php-exec-and-exceptions/ pls check with this link, i am sure it will help you

Comment: AH! Of course. echo $! executes successfully, which makes it return 0.  Use && echo $! and it will only execute the echo if the original command is successful.

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

```
exec(sprintf("%s > %s 2>&1 & echo $!", $cmd, $outputfile),$pidArr, $status);
```

$status=0 if no errors, > 0 if errors